# Why are the synchronous reluctance motors not self-starting?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, electromagnetism

I have been studying synchronous reluctance motor since a month. I am curious to know why is this motor not self starting?
If used with an inverter, this motor can be made self-starting. Or by adding conductors bars on the rotor just like an induction motor, to make it line-start motor.

Synchronous reluctance motors do not have conductors or permanent magnets in their rotors. It is just iron with flux guides/barriers. There is no opposing force in this motor as present in PM motors. I am aware that if position sensor and inverter is not used, the rotor may rotate in any direction that is undesirable. Is there any other reason that this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge includes stuff like rotor inertia and knowing the position of the rotor, without which the stator field cant be aligned in such a way to provide the required starting torque.